# Is mutation needed when using ordered crossover?

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I've implemented ordered crossover for a genetic algorithm solving the TSP.

However, I noticed my algorithm preforms better without mutation enabled and I'm guessing this is because of how ordered crossover mixes some of the genetic information to keep a valid permutation encoding, creating slightly "mutated" solutions.

I feel like this is wrong however? Can mutation be removed when using ordered crossover?

Comment: It’s been a long time since I did this, hence a comment rather than an answer. But: isn’t mutation required to introduce new genetic information? If what I remember about crossover is correct, they cannot, in principle, probe the entire problem space, just a subset of it. Only mutations are able of probing the entire problem space.

Comment: Unless you've already covered the entire problem space with your first generation, @KonradRudolph is correct; you need mutation in order to search more of the space. However, you might just get lucky in that your problem is such that a really good solution can be discovered just via crossover.

Comment: Yes, I know. If you look at the paper @ASantosRibeiro posted (http://ijcopi.org/ojs/index.php?journal=ijcopi&page=article&op=viewArticle&path[]=44) you can see what I mean. Ordered crossover will typically move genetic information to new areas of the chromosome not found in either of the parents. So it kind of acts like mutation. However, in all papers I've seen using ordered crossover this isn't discussed and mutation is still implemented which seems odd considering the results I'm getting.

Comment: For TSP, ordered cross-over does provide mutation characteristics and may be used without mutation, as you can generate any string with ordered cross-over and enough generations. Yet, mutation may provide quicker changes that are not dependent of the parents. Take into attention that although you can generate any string as said before, this still evolve dependently on the parents. Again, as in the answer below, the mutation and cross-over probabilities used, and the specific implementation will balance this differently. I recommend you to test the different techniques and decide by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutation in TSP can have different forms, and as such they will interact with the ordered crossover operator in different ways.

Read this article to understand different types of mutation in TSP: Informatica 35(2011) 513–518 - http://www.informatica.si/PDF/35-4/19_Hasan%20-%20Evaluating%20the%20Effectiveness%20of%20Mutation%20Oper.pdf

Even ordered crossover has several different implementations and therefore will interact differently with the different mutation algorithms: IJCOPI Vol 2, No 1: January-April 2011 - http://ijcopi.org/ojs/index.php?journal=ijcopi&page=article&op=viewArticle&path[]=44

How your implementation of the ordered crossover operator will interact with your mutation operator is therefore difficult to access.

Hope this helped.